# Elementary proof that $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+i \frac{1}{n^2}$ is conditionally convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I must prove that the complex series $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+i \frac{1}{n^2}$$ is conditionally convergent. The catch is, I'm not supposed to use anything "too advanced", meaning I only have in hands the ratio test and the root test, which are pretty much useless, since the failure of the ratio test implies the failure of the root test. We can use the comparison test too.

I managed to prove it using Raabe's test, here goes:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \left| \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+i \frac{1}{n^2}\right| = \sum_{n \geq 1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^4}},$$ the ratio test and root test both fail for $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^4}} = \frac{\sqrt{n^3+1}}{n^2}$, but by Raabe's test: $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} n\left(1 - \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)^3+1}{n^3+1}}\right) = \frac{1}{2} < 1,$$ the series diverges (actually, I used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+goes+to+infinity+of+n%281+-++%28n%2F%28n%2B1%29%29%5E2+sqrt%28%28%28n%2B1%29%5E3%2B1%29%2F%28n%5E3%2B1%29%29+%29) to get this limit, cheated again).

Now, we know that the complex series converges if and only if $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ both converge. The second one obviously converge. And for the first one, both the ratio test and the root test fail, but by Raabe's test: $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} n\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right) = +\infty > 1,$$and the series converges.

> **Question:** Is there an elementary approach to this?

Comment: $\sum (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$ converges because it is alternating and the terms go to $0$. It is conditionally convergent because you can compare it to $\sum (-1)^n/n$.

Comment: @Arthur what do you mean by "compare" in this instance? Usually that means the comparison or limit comparison test, but neither applies to this example, so your comment may be confusing to the op.

Comment: I was a bit quick writing that down, but what I mean is that when you sum the absolute values of the terms, to see if it's absolutely or just conditionally convergent, you have  $1/n<1/\sqrt n$. Therefore the sum $\sum 1/\sqrt n$ diverges, which means that the convergence of $\sum(-1)^n/\sqrt n$ is conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^4}} \ge \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, by direct comparison the series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{i}{n^2}\right| = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^4}}$$ diverges.

To see $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$ converges, let $s_n$ be the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}/\sqrt{n}$. Then

$$s_{2n} = s_{2n-2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \ge s_{2n-2}$$

and

$$s_{2n} = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) - \cdots - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}\right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \le 1.$$

for all $n\in \Bbb N$. So the sequence $\{s_{2n}\}$ is increasing and bounded above by $1$. By the monotone convergence theorem, $s_{2n}$ converges. Let $s = \lim_{n\to \infty} s_{2n}$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_{2n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(s_{2n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} s_{2n} = s.$$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_{2n} = s = \lim_{n\to \infty} s_{2n+1}$, $\{s_n\}$ converges (with limit $s$). So $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$ converges (to $-s$).

Comment: It's not absolutely convergent, but it **is** convergent. Are you just commenting on the original post's approach maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to break it up into real and imaginary parts. Consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_ni)$$

with $a_n,b_n\in\Bbb R$. Then given $\epsilon >0$ if $\sum a_n=a, \sum b_n=b$ we have some $N'(\epsilon),N''(\epsilon)$ so that when $k>N', m>N''$ we have

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^k a_n-a\right|<\epsilon, \left|\sum_{n=1}^{m} b_n-b\right|<\epsilon$$

but then if $\ell>N=\max\{N',N'' \}$ we have

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\ell (a_n+b_ni)-a+bi\right|<\left|\sum_{n=1}^\ell a_n-a\right|+\left|i\left(\sum_{n=1}^\ell b_n-b\right)\right|<2\epsilon.$$

But then both of your original series are convergent, the real part series by the alternating series test since $n^{-1/2}$ is a monotone decreasing function, and the imaginary part is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence of partial sums $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}} + i\frac{1}{k^2}\right]$. We have
$$ S_{n} = S_{n-1} + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}} + i\frac{1}{n^2} $$

From earlier work, we see
$$ \left|S_n-S_{n-1}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^4}}. $$

Thus, $|S_n-S_{n-1}|$ monotonically approaches 0, implying $S_n \to S$. The original series must converge. [edit]*This is very wrong.* See comments.[/edit] However, it is conditional, since
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+i\frac{1}{n^2}\right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^4}} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to \infty. $$

Comment: How does this imply convergence? If you let

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}$$

then $S_n-S_{n-1}=n^{-1}$, monotonically approaches $0$, but clearly $S_n$ does not converge.

Comment: You are right of course, major brain fart and wishful thinking on my end! One would need to show $|S_n|$ is bounded above by something. How embarrassing.